# How do you find the end nodes of a graph?

Tags: sql, oracle

My code currently outputs all the nodes traversed in a graph.

```
CREATE TABLE DAG(
  pid NUMBER,
  cid NUMBER,
  PRIMARY KEY(pid, cid)
);

WITH Ancestor(ancestor, descendant) AS 
(   SELECT d.pid, d.cid
    FROM DAG d
    UNION ALL
    SELECT d.pid, a.descendant
    FROM Ancestor a  
    JOIN DAG d
    ON d.cid = a.ancestor
)   
SELECT * FROM Ancestor;
```

How do I get it to show all end nodes of a graph?

Comment: Sorry, leaving now so can't be bothered to write this out into an answer but you want [this](http://technology.amis.nl/2009/11/14/oracle-11gr2-alternative-for-connect_by_isleaf-function-for-recursive-subquery-factoring-dedicated-to-anton/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about;

```
SELECT * FROM dag WHERE cid NOT IN (SELECT pid FROM dag)
```

Basically it just finds all nodes and removes all the nodes that are parents of another node.

EDIT: After your edit of the question, you seem to want to recursively find all parents and grandparents that don't have a child;

```
WITH Ancestor(grandparent, parent, child) AS 
(   SELECT 0, d.pid, d.cid FROM DAG d WHERE pid=1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT a.parent, a.child, d.cid
    FROM Ancestor a  
    LEFT JOIN DAG d
      ON d.pid = a.child
    WHERE a.child IS NOT NULL
)   
SELECT grandparent ancestor, parent descendant
FROM Ancestor
WHERE ancestor.child IS NULL;
```

Your base case here being the root node (pid=1), use a left join to recursively find all grandparents/parents that don't have a child, and display them as ancestor/descendant.

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0e318/1).

Comment: A really clever approach! It does assume that the table contains only complete, consistent, trees without cycles though...

Comment: I'm a beginner to both algorithms and SQL. Where would this go in my code?

Comment: Your ancestor relation is known as the transitive closure of your dag (is it a coincidence that it is a tree?). If you want to use the TC to determine the leafs you can phrase it like: all nodes n1 where it does not exist another node n2 such that n1 is an ancestor of n2, i.e: `)   
SELECT leaf, ancestor 
FROM Ancestor a1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  select 1 from ancestor a2 where a2.ancestor = a1.leaf
)`

Comment: But as Joachim points out, there's no need to determine the TC to find out what the leafs are

Answer (score 1):

Expanded answer from comment:

```
WITH Ancestor(ancestor, leaf) AS 
(   SELECT d.pid, d.cid
    FROM DAG d
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  d.pid, a.leaf
    FROM    Ancestor a
    JOIN    DAG d
        ON d.cid = a.ancestor
)   
SELECT leaf, ancestor 
FROM Ancestor a1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   select 1 from ancestor a2 
   where a2.ancestor = a1.leaf
)
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot. What is the "select 1" doing? I've never seen this in SQL before.

Comment: It is the presence of a row that is important, not what's in it.  select 1 is an old habit, could have used another constant such as -36, 'a' or even *. If a column is guaranteed to not contain null that could have been used as well